# Ubuntu / Linux latest version

Tags: versions

I need to install Ubuntu / Linux on my laptop that has a Sony Vaio i3 processor with 2 GB RAM and 500 GB hard disk. Which version of Ubuntu / Linux is best supported & easy to install codecs on?

Comment: So what is stopping you from installing one? Ubuntu is free of charge.  "best supported" is a matter of opinion.  " easy to install codecs" Ubuntu and all flavours have 1 method of installing them so there is no "easy method" just 1 method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an OS that has low spec requirements, then you're looking at one of three of the Ubuntu derivatives. [Take a look at this Ubuntu wiki page for more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

- [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net) (LXDE)
- [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) (XFCE)
- [Ubuntu MATE](http://www.ubuntu-mate.org) (MATE)

All three of these would be a good choice for your laptop's specifications.

I would personally choose one of those three over stock Ubuntu (Unity), Ubuntu GNOME (GNOME3) or Kubuntu (KDE) because they have higher minimum system requirements. However, I run stock Ubuntu (Unity) on a laptop with a Dual Core Core 2 Duo @ 1.6 GHz with 2.5 GB of RAM - so it's up to you.

Once you decide which derivative you're going to go with, you've got to decide which [Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) to go with.

Currently, the supported versions are:

- 12.04 LTS (And all subsequent .x releases)
- 14.04 LTS (And all subsequent .x releases)
- 14.10
- 15.04

I would personally suggest using either 14.04 LTS (because it's stable and will be supported for 5 years) or 15.04 because it's the newest version. Basically, just ignore 14.10.

As for which architecture to choose, your processor is basically assured to be 64 bit - so I would just suggest downloading the 64 bit version. The 32 bit version *will* work, but if you have a 64 bit CPU you might as well make use of those extra 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

For this hardware I would recommend 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

LTS are always preferred, especially for new users. And they are supported for 5 years.

32-bit, because there is only 2GB of RAM and 32-bit version uses less RAM.
64-bit should be almost as good.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest version of Ubuntu (15.04), but i would recommend you to install the 14.04 LTS version.See this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: In your case i would prefer the 32 bits